# Transporter Build to Itunes Connect Issue

Tags: macos, app-store-connect, ipa

I have a .IPA File and I have tried using Transporter for the first time for build since in the past I used to use Application Loader (now I heard its not being used anymore).

I have uploaded my IPA file in the Transporter app and it was delivered successfully.

I went to iTunes connect to select the build from the list of builds of my app and its not showing up.

Am I missing a step?
Has anyone encountered this issue?

Comment: Did you find the issue? Will it appear after some time? I've been waiting for a lot of time for it to appear.